# Will arara be able to handle this non-linear compile sequence?

Tags: compiling, arara, lilypond

I have been reading and playing `arara` now since the summer and I LOVE IT!!!!

Prior to arara I used batch and script files that were operating system specific.  Thank you arara for removing this dependency!

So far, I am still struggling with setting up small demo compiles with lilypond, and while I continue to work this out, I wanted to put forward a question (about what I would describe as a complex iterative or non-linear compile sequence) to the developers or other skilled users, so I know whether I can keep this love affair with arara in all my projects.

Clean working directories is my OCD, and so my strategy for texlipse LaTeX projects usually involves structuring it as follows:

[image]

> So the take away from this is that I am preventing Lilpond-book from
>   overwriting my complex directory structures by nesting my
>   output/working compile directories.  This requires two distinct Main
>   files (one created by the other)
>
> - Main.tex (Output) is compiled with Lilypond-book
> - Main.tex (LilyPondPreCompileOutput produced by compiling Main.tex in Output with lilypond-book) is compiled by xelatex or tex4ht.

**Conceptual Problem**

- arara commands are written in a comment like block at the top of the main file.
- I only have one main file until lilypond-book has run.
- After this first build, the sequence at the top of the file which the remaining commands saying build a bib, gls, or tex file are in the wrong working directory.
- Also I can't issue two arara calls using the texelipse builder because the arara code in main.tex will execute fully both times.

**Hopefull solution - Is this possible???**

1. Write complete compile instructions into Main.tex (Output version)

   a.  lilypond-book build on Main.tex with output=LilyPondPreCompileOutput

   b.  xelatex build

   c.  bibtex build (bibunits iteration compatible)

   d.  a sequence of makeindex builds for custom glossaries

   e.  two more successive xelatex builds
2. Launching arara to compile Main.tex (Output version) will generate the LilyPondPreCompileOutput directory and copies of Files and src directories.
3. The successive calls will successfully run if arara can be given a relative directory path pointing deeper into my project structure (i.e. LilyPondPreCompileOutput).
4. Based on documentation I have picked through, I think I can use configured arguments like `% arara: lilypond: { output: "/LilyPondPreCompileOutput" }` in the generic tex compile sequences to get the code in the correct spot.

   a.  I am not sure this is a useable strategy, because I am not sure whether these arguments based on the main project file name are using canonically inferred path names retrieved from the application call (i.e. `test$arara test.tex`), or whether I can insert a new directory before the executed path name in the arara configuration files for each of the builders in steps b through d.

Thanks for making it all the way to the end!  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi! I am in a hurry in the last few days, but I will try to take a closer look at your question tomorrow. `:)` By the way, which version of `arara` are you using?

Comment: @PauloCereda I am using arara version 3.0.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this, and please let me know if theres anything I can clarify.

Comment: @PauloCereda Have you had a chance to look at this?

Comment: @PauloCereda -- any news?

Comment: Señor @PauloCereda, any news? :-p

Comment: @Johannes: `arara` 4.0, but it's still to be officially released, sorry. Hopefully later on this year...